# How to change annotation features for Vision OCR?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-vision

I'm trying to extract text from a local image with Python and Vision, based off [Cloud Vision API: Detect text in images](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr).

This is the function to extract text:

```py
def detect_text(path):
    """Detects text in the file."""
    from google.cloud import vision
    import io
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()

image = vision.Image(content=content)

response = client.text_detection(image=image)
    texts = response.text_annotations
```

It works, but I'd like to specify the use of features like `TEXT_DETECTION` instead of the default `DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION` feature, as well as specify language hints. How would I do that? The `text_detection` function doesn't seem to take such parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following [article](https://medium.com/@annycarolinegnr/using-google-vision-api-22d1fdb755d8) explains it, scroll down to the 'Creating the Application' section.

You need to add a request object to your code

```
request = {
   "image": {
      "source": {
         "image_uri": "IMAGE_URL"
      }
   },    
   "features": [
      {
         "type": "TEXT_DETECTION"
      }
   ]
   "imageContext": {
     "languageHints": ["en-t-i0-handwrit"]
   }
}
```

Then past it in to the request.

```
response = client.annotate_image(request)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can request language hints by adding [image_context](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.vision.v1#imagecontext)  object:

```
response = client.text_detection(image=image,
image_context={"language_hints": ["en"]})
```